# What another rebus?

Tags: rebus

Solve this rebus, and maybe learn a new word.

[image: +phrase+]

Hint:

> Think of all types of phrases.

Hint 2:

> Think positive!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Appositive phrase

Why?

> The plus signs, plus the hint "think positive", may refer to the fact that "positive" is a part of the word "appositive".

Comment: That's it. That hint was too big...

Answer (score 5):

how about

> adage

because

> Plus signs **ad**d, and an adage is a traditional, often philosophical phrase.

Comment: Nope. Nice try.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> catchphrase (as the PHRASE is caught between + and +)

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> *Paraphrase*
>
>  Paraphrase is a restatement of the meaning of a text or passage using other words, and here the word Phrase is restated using the plus signs?

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> [periphrase](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/periphrase) ?

Because...

> periphrase means : the use of more words than are necessary to express the idea(that's why plus symbols)

Comment: No... your on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is an

> additive phrase

Comment: No... not this.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Prepositional Phrase

Because

> Phrase is "between" the + signs and "between" is a preposition

Comment: Closer.... something else.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> rephrase

because

> +phrase+ so it is like add phrase that is somewhat related to 'rephrase'.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Arithmetic expression.

because...

> The mathematical symbols are used in basic arithmetic, and an expression is another word for phrase.